# select one column, split to multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle Database like below:

```
res_code  column1  ...
-------------------------------
001       A
002       B
003       C
004       D
005       E
```

I want to select from this table to get the result like:

```
res_code1  res_code2
-------------------------------
001       002
003       004
005       ...
```

tip: res_code1 and res_code2 both belongs to res_code, can't be duplicated.
Is is possible using sql?

Comment: Everything is possible in computer world. What is your backend? SQL is a general  name used by many backends (it may not be possible or hard in some backends).

Comment: What is your logic for putting codes on the same row?

Comment: Looks like he wants to have them in 2 columns based on Odd or Even res_code!

Comment: @xinchung What's your sql logic?

Comment: I using Oracle Database, PL/SQL;  I need to do soap service interface performance test using loadrunner, the soap service interface has two res_code 
 parameters (res_code  is simcard number), this two parameters has no relationship.  I want generate muliple column res_code file from the database, so loaderrunner can get two paramters by column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply with an SQL like:

```
with odds as
(
select res_code, cast(res_code as int) as rn 
from myTable 
where mod(cast(res_code as int) ,2) =1
),
evens as 
(
select res_code, cast(res_code as int) as rn 
from myTable 
where mod(cast(res_code as int) ,2) =0
)
select odds.res_code as res_code1, evens.res_code as res_code2 
from odds
left join evens on evens.rn = odds.rn+1;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this, use row_number to make `rn` then do `MOD` to split the group.

Doing some arithmetic in main query.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   res_code VARCHAR(50),
   column1 VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('001' ,'A');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('002' ,'B');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('003' ,'C');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('004' ,'D');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('005' ,'E');
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as (
  select t1.*, 
         MOD(row_number() over (order by column1) ,2) rn,
         ceil(row_number() over (order by column1) / 2) grp1
  from T t1
)
select MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN t1.RES_CODE END) res_code1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 0 THEN t1.RES_CODE END) res_code2
from cte t1
group by grp1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e365/3/0)**:

```
| RES_CODE1 | RES_CODE2 |
|-----------|-----------|
|       001 |       002 |
|       003 |       004 |
|       005 |    (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cursor to do double fetch and single insert:

```
declare @res_code1 nvarchar(100), @res_code2 nvarchar(100), @even int

declare @newtable table(res_code1 nvarchar(100), res_code2 nvarchar(100))

declare cur cursor for (select res_code from @mytable)
open cur

-- assume first 2 rows are available
fetch next from cur into @res_code1
fetch next from cur into @res_code2
-- set @even to 1 meaning even value has been fetched
set @even = 1

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  if @even = 0
  begin
    -- fetch @res_code2
    fetch next from cur into @res_code2
    set @even = 1
  end
  else
  begin
    -- insert into table since @even = 1 (has even number)
    insert into @newtable values(@res_code1,@res_code2)
    -- fetch @res_code1
    fetch next from cur into @res_code1
    set @even = 0
  end
end

-- insert the last odd
if @even = 1
  insert into @newtable values(@res_code1,'')
```

Comment: The above code is in T-SQL but I think you'll get the idea